# Why VBO is not working with views_embed_view?

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7

I have a view of bulk operations. All the operations work fine when I placed the view on a page or creating a block view.
But When I embed my view on my page using

views_embed_view('view_name', 'page_1', '1,2,3')

this code where I am passing some arguments to the view. The view displays according to the arguments which I have passed to it but bulk operations does not work here.

I do not know why it is not working. The same view I placed on a page and its bulk operations working and the same view when I embed using the above code then its bulk operations do not work.

What is the problem and how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance...